# CallKit: iOS Integration - CXProviderConfiguration Not Working

Tags: ios, callkit, cxprovider

Having a problem with CallKit integration.  I am creating a configuration like this:

```
    let providerConfiguration = CXProviderConfiguration(localizedName: "XXX")

    providerConfiguration.supportsVideo = false
    providerConfiguration.maximumCallsPerCallGroup = 1
    providerConfiguration.supportedHandleTypes = [.phoneNumber]

    if let callKitIcon = UIImage(named: "IconMask")
    {
        providerConfiguration.iconTemplateImageData = callKitIcon.pngData()
    }

    providerConfiguration.ringtoneSound = "Ringtone.caf"
```

And then creating the provider like so:

```
self.provider = CXProvider(configuration: providerConfiguration)
self.provider.setDelegate(self, queue: nil)
```

Problem is that all of this seems to be ignored.  Custom Ringtone does not sound, IconMask does not show up on the iOS UI (its just a blank).  IconMask is correct and the 3 images are 40, 80 and 120 pixels with alpha channel.  Ringtone.caf is a valid sound file copied in the bundle.

Nothing in this CXProviderConfiguration seems to have any impact at all.  Very frustrating!  I get called back on the delegate function:

```
func providerDidBegin(_ provider: CXProvider)
```

And there I can inspect provider.configuration and it all looks correct.
What am I doing wrong?

The inbound call actually works and I am integrating with TwilioVoice and VOIP push.  So just the UI is not picking up anything in the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if both ringtone and icon file have the targetMembership selected for them in the `FileInspector`
[image]